# Should all react-admin field component props types extend TypographyProps besides PublicFieldProps and InjectedFieldProps?

Tags: react-admin

I've noticed this type pattern in react-admin field component props types:

```
export interface MyCustomFieldProps
    extends PublicFieldProps,
        InjectedFieldProps,
        TypographyProps {
    [myCustomFieldExtraProp: string]: any
}
```

But sometimes TypographyProps is not extended. I have no clue why. I thought maybe a field component props type should only extend TypographyProps when it returns a Typography component.

Some examples:

**DateField**

```
export interface DateFieldProps
    extends PublicFieldProps,
        InjectedFieldProps,
        TypographyProps {
    locales?: string | string[];
    options?: object;
    showTime?: boolean;
}
```

**FileField**

```
export interface FileFieldProps extends PublicFieldProps, InjectedFieldProps {
    src?: string;
    title?: string;
    target?: string;
    download?: boolean | string;
    ping?: string;
    rel?: string;
    classes?: object;
}
```

But then I've found some field components that return a Typography but do not extend TypographyProps. Therefore invalidating my thought.

Like this one:

**EmailField**

```
export interface EmailFieldProps
    extends PublicFieldProps,
        InjectedFieldProps,
        AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I took some time to further investigate. It looks like fields that return a Typography component only are the only ones that extends TypographyProps.

- TextField - Returns Typography for both value and emptyText.
- NumberField - Returns Typography for both value and emptyText.
- DateField - Returns Typography for both value and emptyText.

Fields that may return another component than Typography do not extend TypographyProps:

- UrlField - Returns Link for value. Typography for emptyText.
- EmailField - Returns Link for value. Typography for emptyText.
- FileField - Returns div for value. Typography for emptyText.

I guess it's implemented that way so we don't get confused when passing Typograph props to a field component expecting change in the value component (not Typography). Because it's only applied to the emptyText component (Typography).